# GeoServer REST API - How can I specify a layer name different from the name of my file when creating a layer via a PUT request?

Tags: python, rest, put, geoserver

I'm trying to make a Python script that can create GeoServer layers from data mounted onto the GeoServer data directory. So far, my script looks something like this:

```
import requests


resource_id = "e477fb5b4d5748b9aabb617475e47b01"
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8181/geoserver/rest/workspaces/testws/datastores/" + resource_id + "/external.shp"
data = "file:///data_vault/" + resource_id + "/data/myshapefile.shp"
auth = ("admin", "geoserver")

response = requests.put(url, data=data, auth=auth)
```

This script will successfully create a layer called "myshapefile" with a store  called "e477fb5b4d5748b9aabb617475e47b01" in a workspace called "testws".

The problem is that I'll be creating a large number of layers, so I need the layer name to be the resource id, not the name of the file, and I won't be able to rename the files in the data directory. It's also my understanding that I can't rename layers after creating them using the REST API, so I need to be able to specify the name of the layer in the initial PUT request. Is there a way to do this through the API?

The documentation I was using for this process is here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html#rest-api-datastores-extension

Answer (score 3):

The request you are using will create a data store and configure the feature type automatically. AFAIK you can not control the name of the feature type when it is created. In the request you can specify to not configure the feature type at this point with the parameter `configure` set to `none`.

The second step is to create a new feature type from the data using the `/workspaces/<ws>/datastores/<ds>/featuretypes` URL (see: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html). Here you want to set the `name` parameter but you need to specify the `nativeName` also, to let Geoserver know which feature to use. `nativeName` should be "myshapefile" in your case. I did not find documentation about this, but after a bit of trial and error it worked (also see this link for general advice how to use the REST API: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/create-a-layer-in-geoserver-using-rest - the basic idea is to browse `http://your-server/geoserver/rest` and find your feature type, get the XML representation to see what parameters can be changed with the POST requests).

The final code:

```
import requests

resource_id = "e477fb5b4d5748b9aabb617475e47b01"
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8181/geoserver/rest/workspaces/testws/datastores/" + resource_id + "/external.shp?configure=none"
data = "file:///xxx/myshapefile.shp"
auth = ("admin", "geoserver")    
response = requests.put(url, data=data, auth=auth)

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8181/geoserver/rest/workspaces/testws/datastores/" + resource_id + "/featuretypes"
data = "<featureType><name>" + resource_id + "</name><nativeName>myshapefile</nativeName></featureType>"
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/xml'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

Comment: When I do this, it works, but a new layer is created instead of updating the existing layer name... I wonder what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [geoserver-rest](https://pypi.org/project/geoserver-rest/)(`pip install geoserver-rest`) library. Simply you can pass the `overwrite=True`,

```py
#import and initialize library
from geo.Geoserver import Geoserver
geo = Geoserver('http://localhost:8080/geoserver', username='admin', password='geoserver')

# upload raster file
geo.create_coveragestore(lyr_name='layer1' path=r'path\to\raster\file.tif', workspace='demo', overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Just FYI: In newer versions of `geoserver-rest`, the according parameter name of the `create_coveragestore()` function has changed: Instead of `lyr_name=` it's now `layer_name=`...